# Jetbrains Rider: Show "external code" in debugger call stack

Tags: .net, debugging, rider

In Rider, is there a way to actually show the "external code" in the debugger stack frames, when paused at a breakpoint?
[image]

In Visual Studio, this can be done easily, but in Rider it seems impossible. And, yes, I enabled "exable external source debug":
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there is [this action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDrB2.png) for expanding external frames. In RIDER 2021.2 EAP 1 we are introducing another action in the context menu (which can be activated by right click on the stack frames panel) to make this setting less confusing. [See for details](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-52769)